# How to pass object as parameter in c#

Tags: c#, object, parameters

Sorry, I may be lacking in terminology, but my searches haven't provided any answer despite the trivial question. Here goes -

I have a superclass and wish to be able to create a new object of any of the subclasses with a method like the the following:

```
static void AddNewVehicle(string brand, string model, int year, int price)
{
    V.Add(new Car(brand, model, year, price));
}
```

I imagined that I would be able to do it like this:

```
static void AddNewVehicle(object VehicleType, string brand, string model, int year, int price)
{
    V.Add(new VehicleType(brand, model, year, price));
}
```

...but I'm getting the following error:

`"The type or namespace name 'VehicleType' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"`

Comment: Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Comment: Try using a switch statement in your factory method.

Comment: Would that allow me to use the different subclasses interchangeably, where I have "Car" in the above example?

Could you maybe post an example?

Comment: @EugenRieck, look at his code again ^^

Answer (score 3):

In your scenario you've specified `VehicleType` as a name of the variable declared with a type `object`. You can't instantiate objects like this.

If you can provide more information on your problem, I'll try to provide a more specific answer.

For instance you could add a new property to your `Vehicle` class called `VehicleType` and it would be of type `enum`.

Or maybe you'd like to implement `factory pattern` and use `interfaces` for dealing with a collection if you need multiple types of a vehicle in one collection.

**edit based on the comments:**

There are multiple ways of doing this, so I mention the one that wasn't mentioned by others so far. It's based on `reflection`. Basically you search your assembly for classes that inherit your "superclass" and if their name corresponds with the supplied parameter, instantiate it.
However, we can simplify this process by using a class called `Activator`. All we need is the name of the assembly containing the desired class and it's name. Activator will create its instance for us.

Here's one sample to get you started:

```
public static SuperClass GetClass(string type)
{
   return (SuperClass)Activator.CreateInstance("someAssemblyName", "type");
}
```

Or more info from MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b4wc81dc.aspx

Of course you can modify the properties prior to any further actions, maybe something like this:

```
public static SuperClass GetClass(string type, string brand, string model)
{
   SuperClass sc = (SuperClass)Activator.CreateInstance("someAssemblyName", "type");
   sc.Brand = brand;
   sc.Model = model;

   return sc;
}
```

Comment: Thank you!, I also thought an enum would be a good solution, I just don't know how to implement it in this case.

Let me try to clarify:
I want to be able to call the method AddNewVehicle by passing a parameter that specifies the subclass.
I now have an enum with these subclasses, but how to use it? 

I have my constructors in the subclasses, since my superclass is abstract.

Not sure which information you might need other than that, but please let me know :)

Comment: @kensing, what's the type of `V`? What exactly are you trying to accomplish by the method `AddNewVehicle`?

Comment: V is a list, sorry, I probably should have left that part out of my code example, since it's irrelevant to my question. AddNewVehicle should let me instantiate an object of any of the subclasses that inherits from my superclass.

I want to be able to call the method with the name of my subclass as a parameter, so I don't have to write the code: "new Car", but simply "AddNewVehicle(Car...)

Comment: @kensing, please, see the update and let me know if it's clear enough for you :)

Comment: I appreciate the answers, going with generic I think. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are going for a `Factory` approach, then use it as a factory. A static class, that constructs stuff for. No more, no less. Don't put state in that factory for storing objects (the list `V`).

Then the somewhat debatable static method

```
static void AddNewVehicle(object VehicleType, string brand, string model, int year, int price)
{
    V.Add(new VehicleType(brand, model, year, price));
}
```

What are you trying to do here? You pass an object with the name VehicleType, yet you want to construct a new one in the body?

Then the compiler error:

> > The type or namespace name 'VehicleType' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

That means you either:

- don't have a class with the name `VehicleType`
- don't have a `using` statement that includes the namespace where the class `VehicleType` is declared in
- miss a reference to the project where your `VehicleType` is declared in.

(or any combination of the above)

---

Some more words on the code example you provided

Let's assume that you have these classes:

```
public class VehicleType 
{
     ... some properties, constructors and methods
}

public class Car : VehicleType
{
     ... some properties, constructors and methods
}
```

Then you'd be able to create a factory class that produces new vehicles, something like

```
public static class VehicleFactory
{
    public static Vehicle CreateVehicle(...)
    {
        // conditional stuff that decides what kind of vehicle to construct
        if (...) 
        {
            return new Bicycle(...);
        }
        else if (...) 
        {
            return new Car(...);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new UnsupportedVehicleException();
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps you a bit on your way.

Answer (score 1):

In C#, type information is commonly passed in one of two ways: an instance of the class, [Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.aspx), or as generic type arguments. The latter affords you [static type checking and constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx).

There are other strategies mentioned in other answers, but you may find them cumbersome and inappropriate.

Try this:

```
class Vehicle
{
    static ICollection<Vehicle> V;

    string Brand;
    string Model;
    int Year;
    int Price;

    static void AddNewVehicle<T>(string brand, string model, int year, int price)
        where T : Vehicle, new()
    {
        V.Add(new T() {
            Brand = brand,
            Model = model,
            Year = year,
            Price = price
        });
    }
}
```

Note this:

- Vehicle has the fields: Brand, Model, Year, and Price
- The generic argument on Vehicle.AddNewVehicle
- If you want sub-classes of Vehicle to treat arguments differently, turn those fields into virtual/ abstract properties and override their set/ get behavior as desired.

Comment: If possible, construct vehicle instances outside the function and pass them in. The function would simply be: `static void AddVehicle(Vehicle newVehicle) { V.Add(newVehicle); }`